# Certain LaTeX not displayed in GVim

Tags: gvim, filetype-tex, unicode, conceal

I use conceal and write some LaTeX files in the GVim 8.2 editor on windows. The conceal works fine most of the time but it is unable to display certain characters like ∈ and ⊆. It shows a box with a question mark instead: something like [?]. My encoding is set to utf-8 so I do not know why this is happening. This does not happen in Vim on Linux probably (I saw a youtube video and there these symbols were properly displayed). Is it possible to correct this error?

Comment: Depends on a font you use. Find the one that has those unicode glyphs.

Comment: Jetbrains Mono has the ones you have in your question:https://i.imgur.com/40YDPra.png

Comment: @MaximKim That worked! Please consider adding that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the font capabilities you use in GVim. Basically if a font has those characters then Gvim should be able to show them.

For example, Jetbrains Mono font has those:

[image]